# Big Sur (Intel) is waking from hibernate automatically, why and how to stop?

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake, big-sur, power-management, hibernate

**Quick Summary**

`pmset -g log | grep -i "wake from"` gives the following for "Wake from Hibernate" (full result list bottom):

A) `Wake from Hibernate [CDNVA] : due to EC.PowerButton/User Using AC (Charge:100%)`

B) `Wake from Hibernate [CDNVA] : due to RTC/User Using AC (Charge:90%) 137 secs`

C) `Wake from Hibernate [CDNVA] : due to EC.PowerButton/User Using AC (Charge:100%)`

D) `Wake from Hibernate [CDNVA] : due to RTC/User Using AC (Charge:100%)`

On two occasions over the past few days (A and C) machine was woken from hibernate due to the power button, which is normal. **However, on the two other occasions it was due to RTC (Real Time Clock?) — not sure what this is about.**

**Question**

1. For B and D, what does this mean? Woke up due to AC, clock, both...how and why?!
2. What does CDNVA mean? Couldn't find it in PMSET Manual

**Potentially related**

I'd assume Power Nap only affects when the machine is on sleep mode (which is distinct from hibernate)...Perhaps when Apple refers to sleep here it also means hibernate?? **If it truly hibernated it means it has powered-off so how can it wake if there is no power?**:
[image]

Also I don't have any start up or wake schedule:
[image]

**Background**

Machine: MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015) — Big Sur 11.4

I've managed to activate and use hibernate mode consistently while I was running Yosemite (still frequently use it in the other partition). Recently I installed Big Sur and have been succesfully going into hibernate mode. However, I noticed in some cases my machine had already woken without me interacting with the machine.

`pmset -g log | grep -i "wake from"` full result list:

```
2021-07-24 19:20:09 +0100 Wake                  Wake from Normal Sleep [CDNVA] : due to XHC1/UserActivity Assertion Using AC (Charge:100%)           
2021-07-24 22:04:55 +0100 Wake                  DarkWake to FullWake from Normal Sleep [CDNVA] : due to HID Activity Using AC (Charge:100%) 635 secs  
2021-07-24 22:30:37 +0100 Wake                  DarkWake to FullWake from Normal Sleep [CDNVA] : due to HID Activity Using AC (Charge:100%)           
2021-07-25 14:48:52 +0100 Wake                  Wake from Hibernate [CDNVA] : due to EC.PowerButton/User Using AC (Charge:100%)           
2021-07-25 17:42:42 +0100 DarkWake              DarkWake from Normal Sleep [CDNPB] : due to RTC/Maintenance Using AC (Charge:100%) 63 secs   
2021-07-25 18:17:32 +0100 Wake                  Wake from Normal Sleep [CDNVA] : due to XHC1/UserActivity Assertion Using AC (Charge:100%)           
2021-07-25 22:17:05 +0100 Wake                  Wake from Normal Sleep [CDNVA] : due to XHC1/UserActivity Assertion Using BATT (Charge:58%) 8321 secs 
2021-07-26 00:35:49 +0100 Wake                  DarkWake to FullWake from Normal Sleep [CDNVA] : due to HID Activity Using AC (Charge:89%) 48 secs   
2021-07-26 01:06:46 +0100 Wake                  Wake from Hibernate [CDNVA] : due to RTC/User Using AC (Charge:90%) 137 secs  
2021-07-26 01:39:04 +0100 DarkWake              DarkWake from Normal Sleep [CDNPB] : due to RTC/Maintenance Using AC (Charge:99%) 63 secs   
2021-07-26 02:07:44 +0100 DarkWake              DarkWake from Normal Sleep [CDNPB] : due to RTC/Maintenance Using AC (Charge:100%) 63 secs   
2021-07-26 02:36:35 +0100 DarkWake              DarkWake from Normal Sleep [CDNPB] : due to RTC/Maintenance Using AC (Charge:100%) 63 secs   
2021-07-26 08:57:33 +0100 Wake                  Wake from Normal Sleep [CDNVA] : due to XHC1/UserActivity Assertion Using AC (Charge:100%) 681 secs  
2021-07-26 09:10:41 +0100 Wake                  Wake from Hibernate [CDNVA] : due to EC.PowerButton/User Using AC (Charge:100%)           
2021-07-26 20:38:11 +0100 Wake                  DarkWake to FullWake from Invalid [CDNVA] : due to HID Activity Using AC (Charge:100%) 3637 secs 
2021-07-26 22:05:18 +0100 Wake                  DarkWake to FullWake from Invalid [CDNVA] : due to HID Activity Using AC (Charge:100%)           
2021-07-27 00:06:04 +0100 Wake                  DarkWake to FullWake from Invalid [CDNVA] : due to HID Activity Using AC (Charge:100%) 81 secs   
2021-07-27 00:40:31 +0100 Wake                  Wake from Hibernate [CDNVA] : due to RTC/User Using AC (Charge:100%) 129 secs  
2021-07-27 01:12:41 +0100 DarkWake              DarkWake from Normal Sleep [CDNPB] : due to RTC/Maintenance Using AC (Charge:100%) 63 secs   
2021-07-27 01:42:00 +0100 DarkWake              DarkWake from Normal Sleep [CDNPB] : due to RTC/Maintenance Using AC (Charge:100%) 63 secs   
2021-07-27 07:03:01 +0100 DarkWake              DarkWake from Normal Sleep [CDNPB] : due to RTC/Maintenance Using AC (Charge:100%) 63 secs   
2021-07-27 09:24:35 +0100 Wake                  Wake from Normal Sleep [CDNVA] : due to XHC1/UserActivity Assertion Using AC (Charge:100%)
```

**NB.**

MacOS **does** have a hibernate mode and it can be activated. Yes it does not exist via the drop down apple menu which shows sleep, restart, shutdown as the main power options. My understanding is that hibernate is not standby, sleep or deep sleep. Apple seems to refer to Safe Sleep as some sort of hibernate mode. However, I've yet to see Terminal refer to Safe Sleep (e.g. haven't seen anything saying "Wake from Safe Sleep"): https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mh10328/mac

PS. Wish there was a way to highlight specific rows above. Maybe done via indenting the whole block and putting an arrow on specific rows or simply colouring the specific rows. Not sure if this is possible.